# why do I get a jni error being caused by FirebaeValueEventListener on my netbeans project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I created a program that writes to firebase and the program runs fine when I run it in the Netbeans IDE but when I build it to a .JAR file and run said jar file I get this message:

[image]

Heres my pom XML if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.FUJCode</groupId>
<artifactId>climate2.0</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<name>UsageMoniter</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Climate</mainClass>

                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Im fairly sure I got all the dependencies so i don't know what could be wrong.

If you need anymore information let me know and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,

Tom

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

here in the project folder it shows all the firebase stuff in the dependencies folder:

[image]

But when you look at the files there is no firebase business to be seen, so im not sure what to say...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the necessary third party artifacts into your project, e.g. by extending your pom.xml:

```
<build> 
  <plugins>
    ... 
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
      <executions> 
        <execution> 
          <phase>install</phase> 
          <goals> 
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
          </goals> 
          <configuration> 
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory> 
          </configuration> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you need to add your third party dependencies to the classpath of your application when starting it, e.g:

```
java.exe -cp "climate2.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;lib/*" -jar climate2.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or create a uberjar with the help of maven hade plugin, see [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

This will create another jar which contains all your dependencies when you build your project.

Comment: It seems i get the same error when i copy and paste this command in, forgive me if I'm being dumb here...I posted a screen grab in the edit of my post.

Comment: I've updated my anwser, you may try it like that and make sure the necessary artifacts (Google Firebase) is inside your target folder

Comment: Firstly thank you for persevering through my incompetence, i very much appreciate it and secondly i added another edit showing how all my artefacts are distributed if that is of any use to us.

Comment: You're right, the dependencies aren't in your target folder by default, I forgot that totally, sorry. I updated my answer again. Note: I also updated the start command